# Usar apontador na struct

Tags: c, struct

Queria saber como aceder a um certo elemento de uma struct da forma como estou a definir-la. Aqui está a minha struct:

```
typedef struct {

 char *produtos[200000];
 int contador;

} Produtos,*ProdutosP;
```

Defini `ProdutosP p` como apontador para a struct. Agr acedo á primeira string de  `char *produtos[200000]` usando `p->produtos[0]` mas eu queria **aceder ao primeiro caratere da primeira string.**
Como faço para conseguir o pretendido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Agr acedo á primeira string de `char *produtos[200000]` usando `p->produtos[0]` mas eu queria **aceder ao primeiro caratere da primeira string.**

```
p->produtos[0][0]
```

ou

```
*(p->produtos[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Você definiu produtos como sendo um array de apontadores para strings.
Para aceder ao primeiro caracterer apenas tem de usar mais um `[]`
Neste caso `p->produtos[0][0]`. O primeiro numero entre os parenteses é a string e o segundo o caracter.

Ou seja, o número entre parenteses [desreferencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean) a string na posição `n` e o segundo o caracter na posição escolhida.

O link que adicionei está em inglês se preferir tem um em espanhol na wikipedia.